# make is outputting "No such file or directory" for my Makefile

Tags: c, makefile

I'm trying to write a makefile but I keep running into this error:

```
[jabdo@q0141 lab4]$ make
gcc -c show.c show.h
show.c:1:20: fatal error: "show.h": No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
show.h:7:18: fatal error: show.c: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [show.o] Error 1
```

I tried looking in my directory, but I can see both files in that directory:

```
[jabdo@q0141 lab4]$ ls
ex        show.c  show.h.gch  utmplib.o  who1.c  who2.c  who3.c
Makefile  show.h  utmplib.c   who        who1.o  who2.o  who3.o
```

My Makefile looks like this

```
who3:who3.o utmplib.o
        gcc -o who who3.o utmplib.o
who3.o:who3.c show.o
        gcc -c who3.c show.o
show.o:show.c show.h
        gcc -c show.c show.h
utmplib.o:utmplib.c
        gcc -c utmplib.c
clean:
        rm -f *.o
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I just tried compiling show.c and show.h and got the same error, even though I'm in the same directory

Comment: You can't compile .h files...  The compiler will include them if your `#include` directives are properly constructed in the .c files.

Comment: your problem is not in make file, it is in your c and h files.

Comment: Please, provide the content of your file `show.c` and `show.h`. It's the one containing the error.

Comment: Thanks, you all were right. My `#includes` were wonky, I almost have it sorted now

Comment: @MarcB Make it an answer and I'll accept it